# jQuery throws an error when button is being disabled

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm very confused about `jQuery` acting strange after I run this chunk of code:

```
$('#importUsers').on('click', function() {
        var data = {};
        data.string = $('[name="manuelni"]').val();
        if(data.string!=''){
        $('#importUsers').prop('disabled', true);​
        $('#importUsersFile').prop('disabled', true);​
        $('[for="fileToUpload"]').prop('disabled', true);​
        $.ajax({
            url: 'import.php', // point to server-side PHP script
            dataType: 'JSON',  // what to expect back from the PHP script, if anything
            data: data,
            type: 'post',
            beforeSend: function(){
                $('#opacity').addClass('overlay-div');
                $('#pureMagic').addClass('magic-div');
                $("#fileToUpload").removeAttr('type');
            },
            success: function(php_script_response){
                // display response from the PHP script, if any
            }
        });
        }
    });
```

It says

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

in this part:

```
$('#importUsers').prop('disabled', true);​
$('#importUsersFile').prop('disabled', true);​
$('[for="fileToUpload"]').prop('disabled', true);​
```

[image]

Immediately after page is being loaded. So I don't click on button with id "importUsers".
I tried this:

```
$('#importUsers').attr('disabled', true);​
$('#importUsersFile').attr('disabled', true);​
$('[for="fileToUpload"]').attr('disabled', true);​
```

This:

```
$('#importUsers').attr('disabled', 'disabled');​
$('#importUsersFile').attr('disabled', 'disabled');​
$('[for="fileToUpload"]').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
​
```

And this:

```
$('#importUsers').prop('disabled', 'disabled');​
$('#importUsersFile').prop('disabled', 'disabled');​
$('[for="fileToUpload"]').prop('disabled', 'disabled');
```

All these selected elements are regular buttons that should not make problems when are attempted to be disabled. I'm using `jQuery` v1.12.0. Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you sure error is coming in this part $('#importUsers').prop('disabled', true);​

Comment: I am,as you can see from picture

Comment: check my answer.I am using Jquery v1.12.0 and it is working fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you have unprintable characters in your code, delete last characters in lines shown on screenshot and you should be fine

[image]

Comment: Yeah, you are right. Some of the trollers in my office put character for greek question mark instead of semicolon while I was not there.

Answer (score 1):

The below code is working for me

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#importUsers').on('click', function() {              
            $('#importUsers').prop('disabled', true);
        });
});
</script>
```

**HTML**

```
 <input type='button' id = 'importUsers' name='importUsers' Value='Import Users'>
```

Comment: Above code is working and is tested..So there must be issue elsewhere

Comment: Yeah, your right.. it's just some of mine troll colleagues trying to be funny.. thanks dude anyway